docker-compose run issue 2024: Error: 'ContainerConfig'
I have what seems like a very strange issue that I hope someone has hit before.
I have a docker-compose file that houses a service for redis. Nothing special, I just grab the latest redis from docker hub. I went in to redeploy today and I normally run --force-recreate to down/up the containers, but when I attempt to run --force-recreate today, I am getting weird errors I have not seen before (and this worked fine yesterday).
Strangely enough though, running normal down/up commands works and there is no issue. Am I missing something?
Here are the commands that work to down/up my system without errors:
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down 
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d

Here is the command that should be fine, but it fails with 'ContainerConfig' errors for redis' docker-compose:
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate

Output...
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate
Recreating app_redis_1 ...

ERROR: for app_redis_1  'ContainerConfig'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 203, in perform_command
  File "compose/metrics/decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1186, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1182, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 702, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
  File "compose/project.py", line 688, in do
  File "compose/service.py", line 581, in execute_convergence_plan
  File "compose/service.py", line 503, in _execute_convergence_recreate
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 206, in producer
  File "compose/service.py", line 496, in recreate
  File "compose/service.py", line 615, in recreate_container
  File "compose/service.py", line 334, in create_container
  File "compose/service.py", line 922, in _get_container_create_options
  File "compose/service.py", line 962, in _build_container_volume_options
  File "compose/service.py", line 1549, in merge_volume_bindings
  File "compose/service.py", line 1579, in get_container_data_volumes
KeyError: 'ContainerConfig'
[88001] Failed to execute script docker-compose

Here is the simple docker-compose config for the redis service:
version: '3.8'

services:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379"


Its 20204. Use docker compose in place of docker-compose.

Well, I feel dumb for that for sure so I'm inclined to delete this question...but can you answer one thing? Why would docker-compose up -d --force-recreate fail but does not with docker compose, while the normal commands I used to use like docker-compose up -d and docker-compose down work just fine? It's like a half update, when will all docker-compose commands start failing the same way?

In fairness it should still work. it looks like a bug has crept into docker-compose.

I wouldn't feel dumb or delete the question. I just landed here a week later after hitting exactly the same issue while performing my monthly task of updating an image and restarting a container that I'd been running for the past 3 years. I'm assuming it's a result of a Debian upgrade I performed a couple of weeks ago, updating Docker in the process. Guess I would have hit the issue then if the containers wouldn't have been set to restart: unless-stopped

@dmakovec definitely not deleting the question/answer. Why? Because my staging environment in all aspects is a mirror of my production env, but for "whatever" reason my issue persisted on production, but was/is still irrelevant on staging. I have updated both environments to use the new commands, but this is not a clear cut "just use  docker compose instead of docker-compose" issue now that I've seen the scope, it is weird and I cannot fully debug as there was nearly nothing usable in the logs of the error...either way, I'm glad you figured out your issue

As noted in countless posts here, and as noted in the comments by @ChrisBecke this was a cause of depreciated commands in Docker. It is now 2024 and things have updated.
For whatever reason, --force-recreate with docker-compose now fails on my production system after system updates, while docker compose up -d --force-recreate works as expected. (Notice the removal of -)
Weird thing is I host on DigitalOcean and did run updates the other day via apt-get... and I did notice docker being updated...but this error was not easy to figure out the cause which is why I asked here. It also hasn't effected my staging env so not sure what the cause for the original commands not working is...

In 2024 you just need to use the following command "docker compose up"! I tried and succeeded

I'm very glad you got your issue resolved, this was a weird one based on years of normal use for me. However, I would suggest adding more context to your answer. As you currently have it written, without much info, it probably should be a comment...and that comment had been written by @ChrisBecke

It was this simple. Thanks for this answer.
